# Pause menu animation on click, resume on next click

Tags: jquery, animation, menu

I have a menu animation that I'm using on mouseovers that is working great, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.  When the link is hovered over, the width of a div is animated, simulating an animated underline.  I'd like for the animation to stop if that menu item is clicked, essentially keeping that item underlined, but then resume if any of the other menu items are clicked.  This is for use in a single page website where I basically want to indicate which section of the website a user is on.

Basic code:

HTML

```
 <ul>             
        <li id="contactmenu">
            <a href="#contactpage">contact
                <div class="underlinecontact">               
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.underlinecontact
{
    border-bottom: solid 3px maroon;
    width: 0%;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#contactmenu").hover(function(){
      $(".underlinecontact").stop().animate({width: "100%"});
    },function(){
      $(".underlinecontact").stop().animate({width: "0%"});
  });
});
```

Fiddle is here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewheaton/e3Z56/36/)

I've tried an unbind function to get it stopped, which worked, but then have no clue how to get it started again. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you can condense all of your individual `hover` handlers in to a single one. Also, if you add a `class` to the clicked anchor, you can check for its existence, and only animate when it's not `active`:

```
$('#Menu a').hover(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).children('div').stop().animate({ width: '100%' });
    }
}, function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).children('div').stop().animate({ width: 0 });  
    }
});
```

Then, just attach a click handler to trigger the `mousenter` / `mouseleave` events:

```
$('#Menu a').click(function() {
   $('#Menu a[href*="page"]').not(this).removeClass('active').trigger('mouseleave');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

So, remove the `active` class from all anchors (apart from the one clicked), and trigger `mouseleave` to perform the animation of the width to `0`, then add the `active` class to the clicked anchor so that the animation doesn't occur when hovering.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3Z56/53/)

Comment: Thank you!  That's it exactly.  I figured there was a way to combine it all, but I'm not quite skilled enough in jQuery yet.  Thanks for helping a noob!

Comment: What about having the Home item underlined on load, since it's on the home page?  I tried this:

http://jsfiddle.net/drewheaton/e3Z56/57/

Which works, but then once you hover over "Home" it animates the width back to 0.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Just add the `active` class to the anchor - [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3Z56/59/)

Comment: Dang...I feel stupid.  I tried to add the class but forgot to add the parent...thanks again!